# creating physics body for a SKSpriteNode in order to detect contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skspritenode

as the title suggest, i have issue with creating contact between my enemies sprite and the hero laser(bullet). i create my enemies trough the following method and am adding them to the view.

```
-(void)Enemies{
//not always come
int GoOrNot = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:1];

if(GoOrNot == 1){

    SKSpriteNode *enemy;

    int randomEnemy = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:1];
    if(randomEnemy == 0)
        enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"enemy_spaceship.png"];
    else
        enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship15.png"];


    enemy.scale = 0.4;

    enemy.position = CGPointMake(450, 0);
    enemy.hidden = NO;

    CGPoint location = CGPointMake(450, 320);

    SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:location duration:2.5];
    SKAction *doneAction = [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^() {
        //NSLog(@"Animation Completed");
        enemy.hidden = YES;
    }];

    SKAction *moveAsteroidActionWithDone = [SKAction sequence:@[moveAction,doneAction ]];

    [enemy runAction:moveAsteroidActionWithDone withKey:@"asteroidMoving"];
    [self addChild:enemy];

    _enemyBullets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kNumEnemyBullet];
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumEnemyBullet; ++i) {
        SKSpriteNode *enemyBullets = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rocket"];
        enemyBullets.hidden = YES;
        [enemyBullets setXScale:0.5];
        [enemyBullets setYScale:0.5];
        [_enemyBullets addObject:enemyBullets];
        [enemy addChild:enemyBullets];
    }

}

}
```

then i add the bullets through a mutable array and then adding my bullets to the enemies sprites as their child. that part works. i can create contact between hero and the enemy bullet and it gets detected. what i have issue with is that my hero's laser does not create contact with the enemy thus i can't make the enemy take hit from the laser. i tries adding the physics body to the method i am using but throws all the other sprites into hell and they don't respond properly anymore.

the following code is my collision code which i am using in update method:

```
for (SKSpriteNode *enemyBullets in _enemyBullets) {
        if (enemyBullets.hidden) {
            continue;
        }
        if ([_ship intersectsNode:enemyBullets]) {
            enemyBullets.hidden = YES;
            SKAction *blink = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.1],
                                                   [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.1]]];
            SKAction *blinkForTime = [SKAction repeatAction:blink count:4];
            SKAction *shipExplosionSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"explosion_large.caf" waitForCompletion:NO];
            [_ship runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[shipExplosionSound,blinkForTime]]];
            _lives--;
            _livesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Lives", _lives];
            NSLog(@"your ship has been hit!");
        }
    }
```

is there any way that i can use to create a physics body for my enemies so i can create the contact between the hero laser and the enemies sprite with the same structure i have currently ? any help is amazingly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most certainly can create a physics body for your enemies. Right after this code `enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"enemy_spaceship.png"];` you can add a physics body like this:

```
enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryEnemy; // or whatever you need
enemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryRock; // or whatever you need
enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CategoryBullet // or whatever you need
enemy.physicsBody.dynamic = NO; // or YES
enemy.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO; // or YES
enemy.physicsBody.restitution = 0; // or another value between 0 to 1
enemy.physicsBody.friction = 0.0; // or another value between 0 to 1
```

There are many ways to create a physics body. You can do a rectangle shape, circle shape, outline a texture or draw your own.

You should read the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/) on this subject to get a better understanding of what you can do and what properties are available.

Comment: my issue was far less dramatic that i thought it was. as it is with all the codes sometimes. with the structure i had, i am adding everything at the start of the game to the scene through a method. i just never added the enemies to that method so the collision never took place since that node was showing nil. by adding the enemies at the start and minor modification to my collision code i was able to solve the issue. but according to my question your answer is correct and i am rewarding you the answer. thank you for your help although my issue laid elsewhere.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey - appreciate that.